# Hello world. Исходный код на Java и байт-код

Tags: java, компиляция, байткод

Исходный код выглядит следующим образом:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Вопрос. Как получить результат работы компилятора Java в виде байт-кода?

Comment: Открыть файл HelloWorld.class

Comment: @VladVetrov спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В консоли из директории с `.java`-файлом выполняете:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

и получаете `.class`-файл. Далее:

```
javap -c HelloWorld.class
```

и получаете байткод.

Answer (score 5):

Это можно сделать командой javap, которая включена в JDK.
Пример:

```
javap -c com.mypackage.HelloWorld
```